# Handle response from ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android

Does anyone have a recommendation for the best way to handle URI results from the ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent?

I am finding that applications that handle the intent provide different data back in return. When selecting files from the Download directory in three different file pickers I get significantly different results.

- The KitKat download gallery:
  content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/1438
- Genymotion (CyanogenMod) Browser:
  file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/334SIGCO-PHRH-FEB14.xls
- Android
  File Manager:
  content://com.smartwho.SmartFileManager/mimetype//storage/emulated/0/Download/334
  PhrPrint.xls

I'm concerned that when I release my app I will get responses back from the user that I didn't anticipate in code and it will crash.  Given that the three tools I've tested have all provided different answers, I'm concerned for what will happen in the wild.

Ultimately I will need to read the contents of the selected file into an InputStream and read the data (.xls via jxl) into my data structure.  But first I need to check the data to get the file name and verify the data type so I can provide feedback to the user that they have a valid file type.

I can use the ContentResolver to do that with the KitKat Download Gallery, but the code fails for both of the other options.  Code follows:

```
public void setFileUri(Uri fileUri) {
   ContentResolver resolver = mFragment.getActivity().getContentResolver();

//Check if the file is of the right data type
if(resolver.getType(fileUri).equals(REQUIRED_FILE_TYPE)) {
  mFileUri = fileUri;
  mComplete = true;
}
Cursor cursor = resolver.query(fileUri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
((FileSelectFragment)mFragment).setFileNameView(cursor.getString(
        cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)),
    mComplete);
```

}

Thank you in advance.